# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, data-science

I want to count number of tags per row , but while looping through each row i am getting attribute error even though my datatype for column is object . see the code below .

```
Tag_data.dtypes
Id            int64
```

Title        object
Body         object
Tags         object
dup_count     int64
dtype: object

```
actual code 
Tag_data["tag_counts"]=Tag_data["Tags"].apply(lambda  text:len(text.split(" ")))
Tag_data.head()
```

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Tag_data.dtypes
Id            int64, says that Tag_data has only one column Id

Comment: i didnt paste it properly : here is there proper one :                                                                                    Id            int64                                                                                                                    Title         object
Body         object
Tags           object
dup_count     int64
dtype:         object

Answer (score 0):

Seems data type of Column "Tag" is float.
Try to change it to string before applying split function : Tag_data['Tags'].apply(str)